# Putting the total of a super-group in a sub-group

Tags: reporting-services

I hope I can put this in a way that makes sense. I have a collection of data. First it's grouped by year. Then it's grouped by type. Then we have the individual rows of data with their visibility linked to their type. What we want to do is show totals for each group as a percentage of the year's total.

Example:

| Type A | - | - | - |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| - | Item 1 | $30 | - |
| - | Item 2 | $20 | - |
| - | Item 3 | $35 | - |
| - | Item 4 | $15 | - |
| Total For Type A | - | $100 | 100 divided by 340 |
| Type B | - | - | - |
| - | Item 1 | $35 | - |
| - | Item 2 | $25 | - |
| - | Item 3 | $45 | - |
| - | Item 4 | $20 | - |
| Total For Type B | - | $125 | 125 divided by 340 |
| Type C | - | - | - |
| - | Item 1 | $75 | - |
| - | Item 2 | $40 | - |
| Total For Type C | - | $115 | 115 divided by 340 |
| Grand Total For All Types | - | $340 | 340 divided by 340 |

My problem is getting the $340 from the Grand Total row to the Total Type A, B, C rows. I can get the numerator with =Sum(Fields!inv_detail_amt.Value). But that just does the sum for that group. How can I get the sum of that field for the next group up? Right now I have the SQL get the totals by year and put them in another database field. It's crude, but it works. I don't want to have the SQL do the extra work and only have the report do the summarizing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by specifying the scope of the SUM expression.

Normally when you use SUM() it will sum the values of the scope that the textbox is in, in your case within your Type group.

To change this you can specify the scope, in the case the scope you want to be the entire dataset.

Assuming your dataset is called `DataSet1` then the expression would be something like.

```
=SUM(Fieldsd!inv_detail_amy.Value) / SUM(Fieldsd!inv_detail_amy.Value, "DataSet1")
```

**Note:** The dataset name must be enclosed in quote and is case sensitive.

If you want the total used to be the total of the Year and you have a row group called `YrGrp` then you can use `YrGrp` as the scope. For exmaple

```
=SUM(Fieldsd!inv_detail_amy.Value) / SUM(Fieldsd!inv_detail_amy.Value, "YrGrp")
```